# blurry text and images in Dell studio laptop

Tags: laptop-display

I have Dell studio laptop 1558. When I use IE or Chrome to browse internet, I see the texts and images blurry. However, the texts in windows explorer is sharp. I am using windows 7 home edition. The same is the case if I open any PDF file, the texts are not very readeable. It all started just today.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx) is causing this.  You can go to Control Panel->Appearance and Personalization->Fonts->"Adjust Clear Type Fonts" and try turning it off and see if that makes it better or worse.  Or, if ClearType is off, try turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the DPI setting. Many manufacturers have options where the DPI is adjusted to make images and text bigger when using very high resolution screens. However, a frequent side effect of this is to make images and text (if it is rendered as an image) blurry as the images get stretched to fit the new DPI boundaries.

Check in the Control Panel > Appearance > Display > Make it easier to read what's on your screen section. See if the value is the default 100% or something larger like 125%.

Comment: I haven't checked this yet as I am not near my laptop today. Yesterdeay I had connected the laptop to my TV through HDMI. Just curious to know whether laptop adjusts any settings automatically in the case and could it have changed the DPI or ClearType?